# Does arm 64 ret instruction pass x0' value to the function's argument?

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, calling-convention

I have a question about arm 64 registers. 
  `X0` is for the `function argument passing` and `function return value`.  And the `X30`is for `function return address`.
  There is two code fragments :

one is cpp  :

```
void test(void* arg) {}
```

and the other is assembly code:

```
mov x3 ,x4
......
ret
```

Now I assume `X30` store the address of function `test`  and the the `X0`store the value `0xfffffff`

When it has executed  the `ret` instruction,`pc` will take out the value of the `X30` which is the address of `test` . So the program will run into the function `test`.
My question is if the value of `arg` will be set to `0xffffff`, if not, how can I pass a value from  my  assembly code to the function `test’` argument `arg` in arm 64 platform?

Thanks all.

Comment: I have the impression you don't understand how the `ret` instruction works, but without all relevant code it's difficult to tell. Could you add a [mre]? At least show how your `test` function and the assembly code are called, and the initialization of all relevant registers. You *assume* certain values for X30 and X0, but we want to see it. Please also accurately describe what you expect the code to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**`ret` does not do anything with `x0` at all.  `ret` is just how you write `mov pc, x30` in AArch64**.  (x30 is the link register, where `bl` (branch and link) puts a return address.)

**Your question is really about calling conventions.**  Functions that call each other have to agree on how args are passed and return values are returned.

In the standard AArch64 calling convention

- `x0` is the first arg-passing register for integer/pointer args.
- `x0` is the (first) return-value register for integer/pointer values.

So when you `ret` in a non-`void` function, the caller will treat whatever's in `x0` as (part of) the return value.  (Unless your function returns `float` or `double`, then the caller will look in `s0` or `d0`, assuming a hard-float ABI.)

If you declare your function as returning a large struct by value, the caller will pass you a pointer as the first arg, bumping the "normal" args over by 1.  You're then expected to store the return value into that pointed-to memory.  (And maybe also return the pointer you were passed in `x0`, but I didn't check if that's a requirement or not.)

---

TL:DR if you `ret` without doing anything with `x0`, your function effectively returns the first integer/pointer arg.

Comment: Really thanks for your reply, my test function is a void function, so if it indicates that X0's value will be passed to my function test's argument which is arg, in other words,  I can read the X0' value through arg.

Comment: @darbe: I'm not sure I understand what you're even asking.  When I re-read your question, it made even less sense.  `ret` *returns* from a function, it doesn't call them.  So when `ret` executes at the end of a `void` function, none of the registers have any special meaning.  Functions can modify arg-passing registers before returning.  But on *entry* to your function, the first arg will be in `x0`.

Comment: hi sorry, you misunderstood my question.  "ret returns from a function" I am not meaning that. I mean, I write a c++ function void test(void* arg)(in mytest.cpp) and I also write  a pure assembly code  (in hello.s). The X0 and X30 have been set some value in hello.s,  for example, X30 is set to the address of test, and X0 is set to 0xfffff,  in the end of the hello.s, there is a  instruction. I compile the two file into a executable binary file.

Comment: When the ret instruction in the hello.s has been executed, program will run into void test,my question is  if the arg is set to the value of x0, in other word, arg is  equal 0xfffff.